# APD Transimpedance amplifier stability

Tags: operational-amplifier, photodiode, stability, transimpedance

I have a photodiode amplifier that responds to a pulse of light like this:
[image]

or like this:

[image]

depending on how I change the feedback capacitor.

Every transimpedance stability article I have read online talks about the noise gain and how the input capacitance adds a zero to the noise gain response which can make the amplifier oscillate due to a noise voltage which always present. The noise voltage never has a step response which could give me the results I am getting. It would just always be ringing.

My circuit is not oscillating! The transimpedance response is just underdamped. How do I analyze the transimpedance response? I'd like to have magnitude and phase plots of the transimpedance response so I could find the phase margin and tune the circuit to make it bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your lead inductance in nH or length?  ( including probe ground) And your design specs?  Input Tpw, output Tpw50, distance, Rgain, sensor datasheet?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 lead inductance wasn't specified in the photodiode datasheet, and I am just trying to get a butterworth response with maximum bandwidth. It will be hard to share circuit specifics. I am looking for a more general approach to analyzing transimpedance response and not noise voltage stability.

Comment: could not have said it better than Bob Pease. http://m.electronicdesign.com/analog/whats-all-transimpedance-amplifier-stuff-anyhow-part-1

Comment: use scope probe without ground lead and tip the use 2 pins for sig/gnd on 10:1probe on tip/barrel if > 10MHz.  Use low Cin Op Amp, low noise current and voltage.  Cascade stages to give best BW and SNR

Comment: If the Op Amp is driving a coaxial capacitance load add a series R of 22 Ohms or so or use probe method above.  Add a few pF neg feedback for stability improvement. Lower Rf to increase BW.

Comment: Why haven't you posted a schematic?

Comment: @Andyaka this a design for work, so I don't want to release too much information.

Comment: No circuit and hand drawn waveforms equals guesswork answers. A bit like showing a doctor hand drawn images of a rash on your ass because you don't want to take your pants off!

Comment: Is posting a schematic or drawing one with the tool in the questions of just the transimpedance front end and the photodiode really going to be a problem? Transimpedance pre amps circuits are readily available and its not 'new' tech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days, I have figured out what is going on.

Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foTHHx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The OPA846 is not unity gain stable, and requires a minimum noise gain of 7 to get something like a 45 degree phase margin. The problem I was seeing was caused by my feedback pole 1/(RF * CF) being at a lower frequency than my photodiode zero 1/(RF * CD) because my feedback capacitor (CF) was 5pF and my diode capacitance is an unusually low <1pF (it is an APD). This caused my noise gain (1 + CD/CF) to be almost unity at high frequencies, causing my amplifier to oscillate, but my transimpedance pole 1/(RF * CF) was at a low frequency, causing my transimpedance response to be over-damped (the second hand drawn trace).

Here's a bode plot of that confusing configuration:
[image]

The first hand drawn trace in my question happened when I decreased the feedback capacitance, which increased my noise gain at high frequencies to meet the minimum gain requirement of 7, but my feedback resistor was too small causing the feedback pole to be too high frequency and giving me poor phase margin on the transimpedance response.

Now, I have removed CF to ensure that CF < CD which is necessary to ensure the noise gain at high frequency (1 + CD/CF) >= 7. Then I increased RF to scoot both the photodiode zero and the feedback pole to lower frequencies to get the phase margin I want and stabilize the amplifier. I am considering switching to a unity gain stable amplifier and decreasing RF and increasing CF to push my bandwidth out further.

In the end, the moral of the story is to be careful using not unity gain stable op amps for transimpedance applications with small photodiode capacitances.

Sorry for the low quality question. I was too confused to be able to ask it properly.

Answer (score 1):

The parasitic electric fields across the feedback resistor need to be increased, to compensate for the PhotoDiode hanging on Pin- of the OpAmp.
Just like a scope-probe has 2 resistors (one in the probe and one in the scope) and 2 capacitors in parallel with each resistor, with the capacitors selected or adjusted to implement 2 identical RC timeconstants, for best flatness of pulse response.

Take a couple pieces of solid insulated wire, twist them together to increase the capacitance, and solder across the feedback resistor.

You have just tuned the circuit; now untwist part of the gimmick-capacitor, and watch the pulse response change.

Comment: This sounds like a fun experiment, but how will I know what capacitor size to implement once I've tuned the circuit with this hack?

Comment: Mouser used to sell 1pF--9pF half-moon-rotor plastic trimmers. Solder one across Rfeedback, and adjust. With plastic screwdriver. Since the half-moon is linear with rotation, you can either estimate, from degrees-rotation, or measure with a C-bridge. By the way, this exact problem fell into my lap about 15 years ago; took me an embarrassing 2 days to realize I had to get the external-consultant to simply add a 5PF cap (to compensate for a 80pF photodiode)

Answer (score 0):

"Underdamped" is the same as "nearly oscillating". If you expect the signal to be like in pic#2 but getting Pic#1, it means (a) bandwidth of your amplifier is well below desired, and (b) you might be pretty close to oscillations, so a temperature change or load can throw you into oscillations. This usually happens when there is excessive parasitic capacitance on In- input (ground plane has no void under In- pin), or diode capacitance is not properly compensated in the feedback.